# how to prevent ARC memory leak on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

how to prevent the memory leak on code as shown as below:-

```
[self.teacher requestData:^(NSData *data) {
self.name = @"case";
}];
```

i had tried googled regarding this issue but not worked. Would be thankful if anyone could point me of the correct direction

Comment: That is Objective-C, not Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self.teacher requestData:^(NSData *data) {
    typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
   strongSelf.name = @"case";
}];
```